# How to enlarge indicators and window buttons in Unity?

Tags: 11.04, unity

I have recently installed Ubuntu 11.04 and I really like it. My only gripe is that some GUI elements are too small on the screen. (My screen resolution is 1920 x 1200.) Over the last few days, I have been trying to customize the interface with various tools (Gnome Color Chooser, CompizConfig, GConf Editor), but I haven't managed to find any solution.
What I would like to change in particular is the panel indicators and window buttons:

[image: Indicators]
[image: Window buttons]

If possible, I'd like to keep the default theme.

By the way, thank you for being here and helping other users! :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is DPI - dots per inch.

Easily changed in the Appearance applet.

A quick search brought up this helpful walkthrough by Kevin van Zonneveld:
http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/fit_more_on_one_screen_using_dpi/

Comment: this does not help with resizing the notification area and does not apply to ubuntu 11.10 or unity at all